# Is there any way I can delete individual text messages?

Tags: sms, huawei-u8850

I have a Huawei U8850 running Android 2.3.7 and want to manage my text messages more efficiently. At the moment the only delete options I can see are to delete all thread or the current thread.

However, what I want to be able to do is delete individual text messages (both received and sent). The conversation with my wife (say) will include messages that are just acknowledgements of other messages being received or ones that are no longer relevant (shopping lists, say) and I would like to get rid of those, but keep the more important messages (at least for the time being).

Is there any way to do this or am I stuck with either keeping the entire conversation or deleting it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is press and hold the text message you want to delete. You will then be prompted to select more text messages to delete or just delete the one you have selected. If your Android version  is too old for this let me know and I will emulate your specific version and figure it out for you.

Comment: D'oh. I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Haha no worries, when I got a device with Jelly Bean on it, it took me forever to figure that out.